# Displaying Data from MySQL on Flask Python

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

Does this work? and stored it in a database, now I want to display the same data on my own website, but it doesn't work. Help please!

```
@auth.route('/')
def home():
    def GetBookLink():
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host='localhost',
                    user = 'Salahudheen',
                    passwd = 'Salahudheen1!',
                    database = 'testdatabase'
                    )
        mycursor = mydb.mycursor()

        
        
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ScrapedBooks") 
        DBData = mycursor.fetchall() 
        mycursor.close()
         

    return render_template("home.html", ScrapedBookData = DBData)
```

HTML :

```
{% extends "base.html"%} {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}{% block content %}    
<h1>{{ScrapedBookData}}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Of course this isn't the format I'm going to display it in, but I just want to learn how to display it first

Answer (score 1):

You defined `GetBookLink` function inside `home` function and never calls former. `GetBookLink` function is also missing `return` statement. Please try follwing code which is minimal change repair:

```
@auth.route('/')
def home():
    def GetBookLink():
        mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
                    host='localhost',
                    user = 'Salahudheen',
                    passwd = 'Salahudheen1!',
                    database = 'testdatabase'
                    )
        mycursor = mydb.mycursor()

        
        
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM ScrapedBooks") 
        DBData = mycursor.fetchall() 
        mycursor.close()
        return DBData
         
    DBData = GetBookLink()
    return render_template("home.html", ScrapedBookData = DBData)
```